# How to set up a local development environment for Scala Spark ETL to run in AWS Glue?

Tags: scala, pyspark, sbt, aws-glue

I'd like to be able to write `Scala` in my local IDE and then deploy it to AWS Glue as part of a build process. But I'm having trouble finding the libraries required to build the `GlueApp` skeleton generated by AWS.

The [aws-java-sdk-glue](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-glue) doesn't contain the classes imported, and I can't find those libraries anywhere else. Though they must exist somewhere, but perhaps they are just a Java/Scala port of this library: [aws-glue-libs](http://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs)

The template scala code from AWS:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.MappingSpec
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.errors.CallSite
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueArgParser
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JsonOptions
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object GlueApp {
  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) {
    val spark: SparkContext = new SparkContext()
    val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(spark)
    // @params: [JOB_NAME]
    val args = GlueArgParser.getResolvedOptions(sysArgs, Seq("JOB_NAME").toArray)
    Job.init(args("JOB_NAME"), glueContext, args.asJava)
    // @type: DataSource
    // @args: [database = "raw-tickers-oregon", table_name = "spark_delivery_2_1", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
    // @return: datasource0
    // @inputs: []
    val datasource0 = glueContext.getCatalogSource(database = "raw-tickers-oregon", tableName = "spark_delivery_2_1", redshiftTmpDir = "", transformationContext = "datasource0").getDynamicFrame()
    // @type: ApplyMapping
    // @args: [mapping = [("exchangeid", "int", "exchangeid", "int"), ("data", "struct", "data", "struct")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
    // @return: applymapping1
    // @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
    val applymapping1 = datasource0.applyMapping(mappings = Seq(("exchangeid", "int", "exchangeid", "int"), ("data", "struct", "data", "struct")), caseSensitive = false, transformationContext = "applymapping1")
    // @type: DataSink
    // @args: [connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://spark-ticker-oregon/target", "compression": "gzip"}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2"]
    // @return: datasink2
    // @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
    val datasink2 = glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(connectionType = "s3", options = JsonOptions("""{"path": "s3://spark-ticker-oregon/target", "compression": "gzip"}"""), transformationContext = "datasink2", format = "json").writeDynamicFrame(applymapping1)
    Job.commit()
  }
}
```

And the `build.sbt` I have started putting together for a local build:

```
name := "aws-glue-scala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.1"
```

The documentation for [AWS Glue Scala API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-gluecontext.html) seems to outline similar functionality as is available in the AWS Glue Python library. So perhaps all that is required is to download and build the PySpark AWS Glue library and add it on the classpath? Perhaps possible since the Glue python library [uses Py4J](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23170212/7421645).

Comment: There's an open issue here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/issues/15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

now it supports, a recent release from AWS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html

Answer (score 13):

@Frederic gave a very helpful hint to get the dependency from `s3://aws-glue-jes-prod-us-east-1-assets/etl/jars/glue-assembly.jar`.

Unfortunately that version of `glue-assembly.jar` is already outdated and brings spark in versoin `2.1`.
It's fine if you're using backward compatible features, but if you rely on latest spark version (and possibly latest glue features) you can get the appropriate jar from a [Glue dev-endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint.html) under `/usr/share/aws/glue/etl/jars/glue-assembly.jar`.

Provided you have a dev-endpoint named `my-dev-endpoint` you can copy the current jar from it:

```
export DEV_ENDPOINT_HOST=`aws glue get-dev-endpoint --endpoint-name my-dev-endpoint --query 'DevEndpoint.PublicAddress' --output text`

scp -i dev-endpoint-private-key \
glue@$DEV_ENDPOINT_HOST:/usr/share/aws/glue/etl/jars/glue-assembly.jar .
```

Comment: Thanks... I was able to see the public address for the dev endpoint from the AWS Glue console and copy the glue-assembly.jar locally. Now my scala is buildable locally.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, there are no libraries available for Scala glue API. Already contacted amazon support and they are aware about this problem. However, they didn't provide any ETA for delivering API jar.

Comment: Thanks. That's disappointing, it seems that they would already have that library. But I suppose we will just use python instead, for now.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround you can download the jar from S3. The S3 URI is `s3://aws-glue-jes-prod-us-east-1-assets/etl/jars/glue-assembly.jar`

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-repl.html