# object util is not a member of package com.amazonaws.services.glue

Tags: scala, sbt, aws-sdk, aws-glue

The title is the error I'm getting when running `sbt ++2.11.12 clean update package`. It's caused by this line:

`import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueArgParser`

I was also getting a `Cannot resolve symbol util` error in IntelliJ.

I've tried everything in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952078/intellij-cannot-resolve-symbol-on-import).

I'm trying to use the `getResolvedOptions` method in Glue's util API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably added dependency to `"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-glue"`, but this library handles only Glue resources creation - stuff you can do via CLI or REST API (create jobs, crawlers etc).

AWS did not publish Glue scala API anywhere, so if you want to compile your code locally you have to work around it.

Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50130253/1680826 for an idea how this can be done.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the confirmation!