# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/glue/GlueContext

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-sdk

I'm trying to make a first attempt to access Glue Catalog from scala code.

I already had some troubles while trying Maven to be able to build my project (This helped a lot [How to set up a local development environment for Scala Spark ETL to run in AWS Glue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254077/))

But now I'm trying to run my code in an EMR cluster and I'm getting this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

This is my code:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JsonOptions
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.{DynamicFrame, DynamicRecord, GlueContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, month, year}

object JoinAndRelation {

  private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //Spark session creation with connection to Glue Catalog
    implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder
      .config(new SparkConf().setAppName("TestGlueAccess"))
      .getOrCreate()
        val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext
        val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(sc)
...
```

And this is the error:

```
19/02/08 15:35:26 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/glue/GlueContext
    at org.sergio.poc.JoinAndRelation$.main(JoinAndRelation.scala:41)
    at org.sergio.poc.JoinAndRelation.main(JoinAndRelation.scala)
```

I was able to compile it with Maven adding the **glue-assembly.jar** as a dependency, also tried to add **aws-java-sdk-core** aswell but it didn't work...

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
>   <artifactId>glue-assembly</artifactId>
>   <version>1.0</version>
>   <scope>system</scope>
>   <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/glue-assembly.jar</systemPath>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
>   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
>   <version>1.11.445</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Finally this is the command I use to run it:

> spark-submit  --class org.sergio.poc.JoinAndRelation   --master yarn 
>   --deploy-mode cluster   --executor-memory 2G   --num-executors 2   MyFirstScalaMavenProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Did anyone face the same issue?

Comment: You are missing the class for "com/amazonaws/services/glue/GlueContext" in your classpath. I do not know about spark-submit but have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099115/spark-submit-add-multiple-jars-in-classpath). I think you have to add the `glue-assembly.jar` with `--jar`

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I'm getting this error when I ran it with the --jars option: 19/02/12 07:31:15 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
 at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)

Comment: Actually, it seems to work if I run it in local "--master local   --deploy-mode client", but then I'm getting a glue inicialization error....